# Running an analysis script on files in Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

Can I run analysis directly on files stored in Azure Storage (blob storage maybe)? What I mean by this is I have various image files that I want to run some kind of analysis on. I have a Rust script/application that will do this, and locally, it works - meaning, when I run this Rust program on my local machine pointing my image directly, it does its thing and gives me what I want. My idea is to store these image files in Azure Storage and use the same (or maybe modified) Rust script to do the analysis - I don't need help with the scripting part - just the Storage thing.

Over the top of my head I don't think it's possible, and the only other way I think it can be done is by using Files Storage and mapping it to a VM as a network drive, and run the script on it. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: May I know what exactly are you trying accomplish?

Comment: So I have some images saved on my blob storage. I have written some RUST code that I'd like to run against the images and like get its metadata and save it in the blog storage itself (not locally on my machine). Is that possible?